# Record not creating from non existent contact - email to custom object

Tags: apex, apex-email-service

I have an email to custom object record creation working for contacts that exist in the system.  However, if a contact doesn't exist I can't seem to figure out how to get the record to create with the "requested_by__c" (contact lookup field) as null.  I was able to at least get to the point of sending the email without receiving a generic bounceback from salesforce of:

> List has no rows for assignment to SObjectClass.StrategyTradesEmail.handleInboundEmail: line 8, column 1

I'm hoping this is possible.  I could always keep the contact from populating on the record and have the users enter it manually regardless of if they exist or not.

```
global class StrategyTradesEmail implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler
{ 
    global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.InboundEmail email, Messaging.Inboundenvelope envelope)
    {
        Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailResult();
        try
        {
            Contact[] Contacts = [SELECT Id, Name, Email FROM Contact WHERE email = :email.fromAddress LIMIT 1];
            if (Contacts.size() > 0){
                Contact c = Contacts[0];



                Strategy_Trade__c trade = new Strategy_Trade__c();
                trade.Subject__c = email.subject;
                trade.Trading_Team_Instructions__c = email.plainTextBody;
                trade.web_email__c = email.FromAddress;

                trade.requested_by__c = C.Id;


                insert trade;


                // Save attachments, if any
                List<Attachment> attachments = new List<Attachment>();
                if(email.textAttachments != null)
                {
                    for (Messaging.Inboundemail.TextAttachment tAttachment : email.textAttachments) {
                        Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
                        attachment.Name = tAttachment.fileName;
                        attachment.Body = Blob.valueOf(tAttachment.body);
                        attachment.ParentId = trade.Id;
                        attachments.add(attachment);
                    }
                }
                if(email.binaryAttachments != null)
                {
                    for (Messaging.Inboundemail.BinaryAttachment bAttachment : email.binaryAttachments) {
                        Attachment attachment = new Attachment();

                        attachment.Name = bAttachment.fileName;
                        attachment.Body = bAttachment.body;
                        attachment.ParentId = trade.Id;
                        attachments.add(attachment);
                    }
                }
                if(attachments.size() > 0)
                {
                    insert attachments;
                }
            }
            result.success = true;
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            result.success = false;
            result.message = e.getMessage() + e.getStackTraceString();
        }
        return result;                                                      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't find a contact, just create a new one.

```
Contact c = new Contact(LastName='Unknown',Email=email.fromAddress);
for(Contact record: [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE Email = :email.fromAddress LIMIT 1]) {
  c = record;
}
if(c.Id == null) {
  insert c;
}
```

This way, you will have created the necessary contact. You may want to add some more logic to find a default account to attach the record to, but this should get you started.